# Use intents from another activities

Tags: android, listview, android-intent

I have an application with four activities. The first is an Login where the user enters a name and choose a value from a spinner. This leads to the a Listview which shows data depend on what the user choose from the spinner.

Moving on to the third and fourth activity which choose information depend on which item the user chooses from the ListView. (Im using intens to save the value from the Listview)

From the fourth activity, I need to get back to ListView (Second Activity) and still be able to choose items from ListView.

My question is, is it possible to take a Intent value from 1:st activity and use it in the 4:th activity? (Since Intens usually "Return the intent that started this activity").

I'm working on my thesis and the code is confidential so I can't post any code here.

Hope you guys understands my problem, if not let me know and I'll try to explain it better.

Comment: Paste your code please

Comment: Try to use Shared Preference instead of intent extra.

Comment: Why is this question down-voted? I agree with Haresh, this seems like a case where `SharedPrefference` should be used.

Comment: I'll take a look at SharedPreferences, hope it works out. Ty Haresh and TmKVU for answering! :)

Comment: Took me a while to understand how SharedPreferences works, but it works now! Ty :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can achieve it by shared preference. Use this for shared preference example.

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_shared_preferences.htm

Comment: Yes, that tutorials helped me a lot. Ty :)

Answer (score 0):

Use shared preference and access the values in any activity/fragment. See this [Shared Preference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)